# How to retrieve the id using the label as reference?

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML, how can I retrieve the ID of the `input` from the tag's `name` in JavaScript?

```
<div class="named-tags">
     <label for="radio_01" class="radio" >
         <input type="radio" name="Name[labeled_tags][]" value="01" id="radio_button_01">
        Fblabel
         <span class="control-indicator">  </span>
         </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please further clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to get the id of radiobutton using the label. The radio buttons are created dynamically and we won't know the id of the radiobutton . So we need to do this method.  I found help to get label associated an element using Id but cannot find id using a label. I have number of radio button which are created like this . My aim is to select the radio button according to a utm tag value. Further more this radiobutton are hidden so  it cannot be selected by user.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`document.getElementsByName('Name[labeled_tags][]')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) will return an array of elements with the specified tag.

You're most likely wanting to select the very first element with the tag name, in this case you would use `document.getElementsByName('Name[labeled_tags][]')[0]`

```js
let inputElem = document.getElementsByName('Name[labeled_tags][]')[0];
console.log(inputElem.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="named-tags">
 <label for="radio_01" class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="Name[labeled_tags][]" value="01" id="radio_button_01"> Fblabel
  <span class="control-indicator"> </span>
 </label>
</div>
```